# How can I prevent connman immediately reconfigures the network when I change the .config file?

Tags: linux

I use connman for the configuration of the network.

I noticed as soon as I change the entry `IPv4=` in `/var/lib/connman/my.config` Linux immediately reconfigures the network to the new ip address. But I don't want that. My desired behaviour is it should just reconfigure on boot-up of my embedded device.
How do I do that?

Or is there a magic setting for connman, something like: `DoNotImmediatelyReconfigure=yes`?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found out `connman` does not have such setting `DoNotImmediatelyReconfigure`. So I solved it by editing a copy of that config file `~/my.config` which I copy over to `/var/lib/connman/my.config` during Linux-startup before the networking comes up. Therefore I created a `systemd` service which calls my script for replacing that `connman` config file, and that service is called before the networking service.